# Definite integral 21

Tags: calculus

Find
$$\int\limits_{r,r'}\left(\frac{1}{r}-\frac{1}{r_0}-\frac{1}{2a^2}(r^2_0-r^2)+\frac{1}{2a^2}(r^3_0-r^3)\right)^{\frac{-1}{2}}dr$$
I tried some substitutions such as
$$r^2_0-r^2 = y$$
\but it gets complicated , is there an anti-derivative for it ?\

Comment: Please show some detailed efforts. Also, what exactly does $r,r'$ in the integration limit mean?

Comment: r is the independent variable and r' is a constant @Alex Francisco